# Russian domain settings on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, server.xml

I have registered Russian domain in server.xml, but why it redirects to the ROOT. Don't find host in server.xml. Can anyone suggest why?
Config here:

```
    <Host name="www.мир-директа.рф" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Alias>мир-директа.рф</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="mir-direkta" debug="0" privileged="true" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
        prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" 
        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
      </Host>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
https://www.punycoder.com/[1](https://www.punycoder.com/)

and then value from above web site add to host name.

Also if you use apache http server, add it to httpd.conf

Comment: Any news? Using above approach i successfully registered domain:
www.зоран-ђурић.срб

with settings:

<Host name="xn----7sbugxeod0a3m4d.xn--90a3ac" ...

Comment: It work!)) Thanks!
     <Host name="xn----8sblemcpk1bdy.xn--p1ai" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  <Alias>xn----8sblemcpk1bdy.xn--p1ai</Alias>
  <Context path="" docBase="mir-direkta" debug="0" privileged="true" />
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
  prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" 
  pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
   </Host>